# Php to ssl proxy

Tags: php, ssl, proxy

Is it possible to find a php module that can connect with ssl proxy, without need for install php or a apache mods?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve, but either PHP's cURL library or `fopen()` function should do what I think you're looking to do.

cURL does need to be installed (but is often present by default). However, I believe the slower `fopen()` function should be available in most shared hosting environments (which is what I assume you're using).

Comment: I dont have options to install mods in to the programs, so I need to encrypt cURL and `fopen()` connects, kinda like VPN. - At the web server my only options is to use php or CGI, but I do not know about CGI. The other end is a private server, but there are jobs on the web server using `fopen()` and this can not be changes.

Comment: Maybe it's me who does it the wrong way. But I'm thinking of making an encrypted connection and possibly send traffic around on the other side.

Comment: Can you explain the application you're developing? What you're trying to achieve will dictate the most appropriate solution. cURL/fopen support secure connections without additional modules.

Comment: It is a control panel for my old boys clan. The troubles is to protect the passwords, there is transfer on login an in files.

Comment: Some of it is for Counter strike (rcon system), other thinks is for ftp. (Other games and programs like CoD, TeamSpeak, reboots and remove backups.) Right now i'm look for a way to encrypt the data before I start to actives thinks and make new ideas. (Maybe bigger things if it's good.) But the small ideas is just to make a php class and setup a ssl proxy services. - I need to say the private server is a windows which also gives a headache and i need a clean system. (I need the options to can make a setup.exe) A other thinks like mods or I write mods for game servers is not an option.

Comment: So basically you're wanting to fetch a page from somewhere else that requires a password, but you want to protect the password in transit using HTTPS? If this is the case, just use the cURL library if available.

Comment: I dont have the options for https on the web server. I need to do this with out a preshare key. :) I need a Virtual SSL connects simuler the VPN. And the counter strike's rcon system dot understand encrypted connection?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the rcon system you're targeting, nor do I really understand what you're trying to create.

Comment: The rcon is remove control (console control) for the CS server. The php rcon class/api... It will be like make a php class for ssh, only using cURL or `fopen()`. It is too easy to hack password from rcon, just as easily as telnet.

Comment: So are you trying to create a web interface for rcon?

Comment: I need a php class there can do some think like VPN.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just don't understand the service you're trying to consumer or the application you're trying to build. I'm not a gamer at all!

Comment: Yes, I understand what a VPN is. :-)

Comment: You need to imagine having to build a web console to ssh with only cURL or `fopen()` Just the comedian and commands are different. eg I will write _rcon changelevel map-name_ to changes map. It also has a command to login etc. But I have all this. It is just to easy to hack if have en program there send the rcon password 10 times within one hour! And several other things. (It is commonplace that there are stolen Steam account and game server is attacked and hacked just for fun.) So to do all this easy I need to encrypted data from the web space to your private (dedicated) server on a new port

Comment: Sorry for my English. _Remove control_ = **Remote controls** :(

Comment: It must be all data as if it were a vpn. I do not have much folding space in the framework. So I got the idea that maybe a ssl proxy could do it.

Comment: You're writing better English than I could write Danish! Okay, so if I've got this right, you're writing a client in PHP to connect to an rcon server. The PHP client needs to securely communicate with the rcon server, right? How do you this depends on the protocol you use to connect to the rcon server.

Comment: The protocol is just hello, bye and so on like much else. So far as I understand it is binary data which may be put round on hello etc to create the link _/fx/f5/.._ etc. But if the data is encrypted, the game server has no opportunity that can decrypt the data. - So everyone can see all the data, passwords etc

Comment: I've done a quick google search as to the underlying protocol. I don't think PHP is suitable; I can't help with this! Sorry.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

A fine day I will rent a cloud server :'( 

- And there is no php class who can make a encrypted bridge there will help whit this?

Comment: If you were connecting to it via SSH, HTTPS, etc you could do it with cURL. But as far as I'm aware, it uses a proprietary protocol.

Comment: I have been slow in it. Have to much to think about :P But yah i think i can do it with CURLOPT_PROXY

Comment: ******. I have no desire to rebuilt the php rcon system :'(